# Vertically aligning figures on their center using subcaption package

Tags: subcaption

Is there a way to make figures vertically align on their centers using the subcaption package?

Currently I get the following result:[image]

The captions below them are vertically aligned on their tops. This is as intended. 
I want the figures to be vertically aligned on their centers. Is this possible?

I am using the following latex code:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}\centering
\includegraphics{Img/Ramsey_Gijs.pdf}
\caption{Schematic representation of Ramsey experiment. Figure from     \citep{Lange2012Quantum}}
\label{fig:Ramsey_gijs}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}\centering
    \includegraphics{Img/electron_T2star.pdf}
\caption{$T_2^*$ decay of the electronic-spin.}
\label{fig:electron_T2*}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{some caption} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You can perhaps use the solution in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175201/  (Oh, and please always add *complete* examples with the necessary packages etc., so that we can copy-paste and compile the code directly.)

Comment: Perhaps this question here provides a method: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170713/3-subfigures-in-a-row-different-sizes-how-to-manually-adjust-the-spaces-in-bew .  Unfortunately, it is a manual `\raisebox`.